# count all records columns with value 0 or 1 in mysql/php

Tags: mysql

[image: Mysql Table]

Please help me friends. I have attached a screenshot of my table I wish to count all columns with value 0 or  1 where buno="$busno".

Sorry But I don't have any code. I have database table and I don't know how to query at such condition. In the table you can see fields busno with seat A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2......N1,N2,N3 and N4. They have only 2 values 1 and 0. 0 for vacant and 1 for booked. I wish to find out how many seats are left (in numbers like 10 0r 20) for a particular busNo. Are you getting my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Get the result row in PHP with the query buno = "$busno", and iterate resultset in php and count the number you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate more like with some code snipped

Comment: GIve the snippet which you are trying to, So that I can correct the problem you are facing

Comment: select count(*) from $tblName where busno='$busno' ;  It will count no of tables with busno=$busno.  But I wish to count no of o's or 1's for a particular busno. Please check attached image for db table

Comment: Try to do the full code and paste the snippet. You haven't read the results from resultset. Your query will not give the result required to iterate try select * from $tblName where busno='$busno'

Comment: Sorry But I don't have any code. I have database table and I don't know how to query at such condition.                                                                                In the table you can see fields  busno with seat A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2......N1,N2,N3 and N4. They have only 2 values 1 and 0. 0 for vacant and 1 for booked. I wish to find out how many seats are left (in numbers like 10 0r 20) for a particular busNo.  Are you getting my problem?

Comment: Then you suppose to learn to do that. Here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php. You can use the query in the previous comment

Comment: LOL I already know how to run a query...I am asking you a single question are you getting my problem other than code?

Comment: Sorry But I don't have any code. I have database table and I don't know how to query at such condition. In the table you can see fields busno with seat A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2......N1,N2,N3 and N4. They have only 2 values 1 and 0. 0 for vacant and 1 for booked. I wish to find out how many seats are left (in numbers like 10 0r 20) for a particular busNo. Are you getting my problem?

Comment: Try [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)